# How to add in MongoDB some object to one array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express

I have an application in `angular`, `express`, `mongodb`, `nodejs`.

This is my Schema :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var FirstSchema = new Schema({
    creator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    object1: String,
    object2: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('First', FirstSchema);
```

And in this part i save data to the Mongo database:

```
.post('/addfirst', function(req, res){
            var first = new First({
                    creator: req.decoded.id,
                    object1: req.body.object1,
                    object2: req.body.object2
                });
            first.save(function(err, newFirst){
                    if(err){
                        res.send(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    io.emit('first', newFirst);
                    res.json({message: "New first Created!"});
                });
        })
```

If I have one text input, how I can add some `objest1` inside? something like this: `object1: [{object1_1},{object1_2},{object1_3},{object1_4}]`?

Answer (score 0):

You should define your `object1` as `Array` type:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var FirstSchema = new Schema({
    creator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    object1: Array,
    object2: String
});
```

and create your instance like the following:

```
var first = new First({
   creator: req.decoded.id,
   object1: [{<object1_1>},{<object1_2>},{<object1_3>},{<object1_4>}],
   object2: req.body.object2
});
```

Comment: Mayby you know, how i can add some this objects using my input: <input type="text" id="" class="form-control floating-label" name="first_name" ng-model="first.firstData.object1" placeholder="Object1" >?

Comment: Could you explain your question more deeper?

Comment: Object1 - this is, for example, list of shops or one shop. Object2 - street. This data i have in first table, for example "Shops": {object1: [{shop1},{<shop2>},{<shop3>}], object2: street1}, {object1: [{shop4}], object2: street2} Second table - this is "investor". For investor i want to have <select> with all this shops: shop1, shop2, shop3, shop4...And for this, i don't know how to add shops to one street and have opportunity to insert every shop in single <option> in <select>